# Loop Stops instead of continuing to next input after condition is met

Tags: python

I'm doing an assignment for class, and I chose to do something like a text-style adventure game, but there's something wrong as soon as I go into a battle. It's supposed to loop until either the enemy's health reaches zero or the player's health reaches zero, it basically does a few iterations of the loop but doesn't continue the code. Here is how I have the code set up for battles with an example of what's supposed to happen after, and then what's happening after I execute the program.

```
def game():
import random
att=random.randint(15,30)
health=100
defen=random.randint(10,20)
print("Your stats are:\n")
print("Attack Points:",att)
print("HP:", health)
print("Defense Points:", defen)
```

There's more code that continues on from here, but I will skip ahead to a battle

```
 skel_att=random.randint(10,20)
 skel_health=30
 skel_def=random.randint(8,12)
 while skel_health > 0 and health > 0:
    print("You attack the skeleton!")
    dam_at_skel=att-skel_def
    skel_health=skel_health-dam_at_skel
    print("The skeleton attacked!")
    skel_dam=skel_att-defen
    health=health-skel_dam
    print("Oh no! Your health is:", health)
    if skel_health > 0 or health > 0:
        continue
    elif health == 0:
        print("The skeleton lays his final blow and you fall to the cold stone floor. The villagers will never find your body, but at least the skeleton will have a buddy in his afterlife!\nEnding Four: Spooky Scary Skeletons\nTry Again!")
    elif skel_health == 0:
        print("You land your final blow and the skeleton falls to pieces on the floor. You grab the EPIC SWORD and feel prepared to take on the dragon!")
        new_heal=100
        att=att+5
        print("With the sword in hand you feel reinvigorated and energized. Your health has been healed in full!\nThe only places left to go is up or out the door. Where do you go?")
        fourth_choice = str(input())
```

Here is what happens when I run the skeleton battle

```
    game()
Your stats are:

Attack Points: 28
HP: 100
Defense Points: 11
You are the epic hero of legend. At least as epic as this text based adventure can get.
 You approach the dark castle belonging to the evil dragon.
 Upon entering the castle there's only a few directions you can go. Up the grand staircase, down the left passage, down the right passage, or back out the front door. Probably not a good idea to go upstairs yet since the dragon is there, but it's your funeral. 
 Will you go up, left, right, or leave?
Right
You go down the right corridor. Up on the wall there is an EPIC SWORD fit for an epic hero of legend like you. It's much more fitting than the frying pan you've been carrying at least! But oh no, a skeleton popped out! And he is standing between you and the EPIC SWORD. Time to send this skeleton back to the graveyard!
You attack the skeleton!
The skeleton attacked!
Oh no! Your health is: 91
You attack the skeleton!
The skeleton attacked!
Oh no! Your health is: 82
```

It basically just ends without continuing on to the next prompt. How do I fix this?

Comment: Think about the case where `health == 82` and `skel_health == 0`. Neither of the `elif`s will be hit (because the `if` is True) and the `while` loop condition will be False.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the skeleton is dead, you continue in `if skel_health > 0 or health > 0:`,
and `skel_health > 0 and health > 0` is false so the you basically break from the loop. To fix it, just remove the first `if` (`skel_health > 0 or health > 0`).

Also, you should probably change `skel_health == 0` to `skel_health <= 0` since you might deal more damage than the skeleton's hp. (As well as `health <= 0`)

Answer (score 1):

This line of code is the problem:

```
if skel_health > 0 or health > 0:
    continue
```

This if statement asks "are either the hero or the skeleton still alive?"

But that's the wrong question to ask -- you actually want to ask if either of them is **dead**.

And the next two if statements already ask that.  (Although I would change those to ask if their health is **less than or equal** to zero, not just **equal** to zero.)

Just take out that if statement.